# How continue php script execution on exception in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, uncaught-exception

When I execute my script something went wrong and an exception is thrown, but instead of stop the all script. How can I tell to zend to continue ?

This error appear when I fetch a mail I have a try catch block but it doesn't catch.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mail\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Line "X-Assp-Message/IP-Score:
```

Thanks.

My code is a simple class to fetch mail :

```
$listm  = new Zend\Mail\Storage\Pop3(array('host' => $this->mServer,'user' => $this->mMail, 'password' => $this->mPassword));

foreach ($listm as $msgp3)
{
    try 
    {
        e($msgp3->from);
        e($msgp3->to);
        e($msgp3->subject);
        e($msgp3->date);
        e(strtotime($msgp3->date));
        e($msgp3->messageid);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        e($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And my code stop at the 10em mail, so how make to tell to Zend to doesn't stop ?

Comment: It will be a better look if you can post your code.

Comment: "I have a try catch block but it doesn't catch." - then you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The point of an Exception is to tell you that something bad has happened, and you need to build code to handle that properly. Without seeing your code, it's kinda hard to debug though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want not to stop a process when a exception has been pointed. You can use a try and catch method. Like this:

```
 try {
    DoSomethingReallyBad()
 }
 catch(RuntimeException $e) {
    // do nothing
 }

 // go further
```

I must say when a exception is called. The process of your last task is quitted.

Note: I didn't test this!

Comment: In fact the exception is really catch cause i can print the $e->getMessage(); but the real problem is that the script stop here.

Answer (score 0):

How are you catching the exception? Can you supply the try/catch code in your question please?

In Zend you need to use the full zend exception class that is being thrown. In this case it is `Zend\Mail\Exception\RuntimeException`, which becomes `Zend_Mail_Exception_RuntimeException`.

```
try
{
  // ...
}
catch (Zend_Mail_Exception_RuntimeException $e)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found where was my problem :

The error is return when i fetch the message here so in the for instruction :

```
foreach ($listm **as $msgp3**)
```

To catch any error when the message is fetch i have to fetch this way :

```
$maxMessage = count($messageList);
        for($i = 0; $i < $maxMessage; $i++) 
        {
            try{
                $msgp3 =  $messageList->getMessage($i);                 
                //--- WORK ON msgp3
                }catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'E2->'.$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

And now my script continue...